# Google Play Developer Console - Supported devices 0

Tags: android, google-play

I just trying to publish my android app, I signed my application from my keystore, but Google Play console displaying me supported devices is zero. I am using Android SDK only for my app. Any reason why this so ??

[image]

Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.info.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.harware.telephony"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- Activities -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.info.SplashActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.Terms"
            android:label="@string/terms_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.SetPin"
            android:label="@string/set_pin_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.AddEditBuddy"
            android:label="@string/manage_friends_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.Login"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:label="@string/login_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.Backup"
            android:label="@string/backup_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.RestoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/restore_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.ClearData"
            android:label="@string/clear_data_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.Settings"
            android:label="@string/setting_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.StolenMode"
            android:label="@string/stolen_setting_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.AppPin"
            android:label="@string/apppin_setting_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.Lock"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/lock_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.Home"
            android:label="@string/home_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.SMSCommands"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_smscommands" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.info.FileExplore"
            android:label="@string/restore_title" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Receivers -->

        <receiver android:name="com.info.BasicFuzz" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.info.IncomingSMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Services -->

        <service android:name="com.info.ResetService" />
        <service android:name="com.info.SmartFuzzService" />
        <service android:name="com.info.GPSLocationService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a char `'d'` in `uses-feature android:name="android.harware.telephony"`